In ASP.net Core MVC I have logged in succesfully, but I'm getting null access token when verifying it
I was able to successfully log in with Facebook Auth, but after that I'm getting null access_token
Here is my code:
Homecontroller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TSG.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using TSG.Services;

namespace TSG.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IFacebookService _facebookService;

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context, IFacebookService facebookService, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _facebookService = facebookService;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Portfolio()
        {
            var feedbackList = _context.FeedbackResponses
                                       .Include(f => f.User)  // Eagerly load the related User entity
                                       .OrderByDescending(f => f.DateSubmitted)
                                       .Take(10)
                                       .ToList();
            return View(feedbackList);
        }

        public IActionResult Feedbacks()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult PrivacyPolicy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult TermsOfService()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult CopyrightPolicy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult CookiesPolicy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [Route("DataDeletion")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DataDeletion([FromBody] DataDeletionRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.UserId))
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid request.");
            }

            // Authenticate the user
            var authenticatedUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (authenticatedUserId != request.UserId)
            {
                return Unauthorized("You are not authorized to delete this user's data.");
            }

            // Perform data deletion logic based on the user ID
            var feedbacks = _context.FeedbackResponses.Where(f => f.UserId == request.UserId).ToList();
            if (feedbacks != null)
            {
                _context.FeedbackResponses.RemoveRange(feedbacks);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Ok("User data deleted successfully.");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                // Handle the error appropriately
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}" });
            }

            var info = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            if (info.Principal == null)
            {
                // Handle the error appropriately
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = "Error loading external login information." });
            }

            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            _logger.LogInformation("AccessToken Retrieved: {AccessToken}", accessToken);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Access token is missing.");
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = "Access token is missing." });
            }

            JObject userData = await _facebookService.GetUserProfileAsync(accessToken);

            var userId = userData["id"].ToString();
            var userName = userData["name"].ToString();
            var userProfilePictureUrl = userData["picture"]["data"]["url"].ToString();

            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    Id = userId,
                    UserName = userName,
                    ProfilePictureUrl = userProfilePictureUrl,
                    DateLoggedIn = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
                _context.Users.Add(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            // Sign in the user
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(info.Principal));

            // Redirect to the return URL
            if (returnUrl != null && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }




        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error(string errorMessage = null)
    {
        var errorViewModel = new ErrorViewModel
        {
            RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage ?? "An error occurred while processing your request."
        };
        return View(errorViewModel);
    }
    }
}


I was able to successfully log in and have the access_token here in externalcallbacks.
feedbackcontroller:
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TSG.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TSG.Services;

namespace TSG.Controllers
{
    public class FeedbackController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IFacebookService _facebookService;
        private readonly ILogger<FeedbackController> _logger;

        public FeedbackController(ApplicationDbContext context, IFacebookService facebookService, ILogger<FeedbackController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _facebookService = facebookService;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitFeedback(FeedbackViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    // Retrieve the access token
                    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
                    _logger.LogInformation("AccessToken Retrieved: {AccessToken}", accessToken);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("Access token is missing.");
                        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = "Access token is missing." });
                    }

                    JObject userData = await _facebookService.GetUserProfileAsync(accessToken);

                    var userId = userData["id"].ToString();
                    var userName = userData["name"].ToString();
                    var userProfilePictureUrl = userData["picture"]["data"]["url"].ToString();

                    var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        user = new User
                        {
                            Id = userId,
                            UserName = userName,
                            ProfilePictureUrl = userProfilePictureUrl,
                            DateLoggedIn = DateTime.UtcNow
                        };
                        _context.Users.Add(user);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                    var feedback = new FeedbackResponse
                    {
                        UserId = userId,
                        FeedbackText = model.FeedbackText,
                        JobTitle = model.JobTitle,
                        Relationship = model.Relationship,
                        DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now,
                        User = user
                    };

                    _context.FeedbackResponses.Add(feedback);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                // Return the Error view if the model state is invalid
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = "The feedback form contains invalid data. Please correct the errors and try again." });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error submitting feedback");
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = "An error occurred while submitting feedback. Please try again later." });
            }
        }
    }
}


But here, in Submit feedback the access_token is always missing...
here's my program.cs for reference:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TSG.Models;
using TSG.Services;

namespace TSG
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Load secrets from environment variables
            var tsgDbConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TSGDB_CONNECTION_STRING");
            var facebookAppSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET");
            var googleClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tsgDbConnection) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(facebookAppSecret) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleClientSecret))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("One or more environment variables are missing.");
            }

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // Add IHttpContextAccessor
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            // Register FacebookService with HttpClient
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IFacebookService, FacebookService>();

            // Authentication configuration
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = facebookAppSecret;
                facebookOptions.Fields.Add("id");
                facebookOptions.Fields.Add("name");
                facebookOptions.Fields.Add("picture");
                facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
                facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
                facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            })
            .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
            });

            // Database configuration
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(tsgDbConnection));

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

I tried making custom access_token, but failed.

Hi ArTa, seems you are missing save AuthenticationTokens before logging successfully.
